# Why is this button does not respond？

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 300.0, 43.0, 43.0)];
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2f
                     delay: 0.0f
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                animations: ^(void){[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 350.0, 43.0, 43.0)];}
                completion: nil];


UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 30)];
[button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Hi, What issues that you have. Can you explain clearly

Comment: I add the code above to a viewController, when running, the button cannot be touched

Comment: App crashes while touching the button? You can not see the button at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try amending your animateWithDuration: see below

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2f
                         delay: 0.0f
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                    animations: ^(void){[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 350.0, 43.0, 43.0)];}
                    completion: nil];
```

Within the options property I've added the value `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`

Answer (score 0):

Make below change in Button definition:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

And you method should be like below:

```
-(IBAction)buttonHandle:(id)sender
{
}
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: add UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able touch the button (if the click is not working) then

write the code

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to action perform on button so try this code.

```
      UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
      [button setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 30)];
      [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button addTarget:self            action:@selector(buttonPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

      [self.view addSubview:button];

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    //put code here you want to perform action on button
}
```

Comment: add UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction, I have done